Using Laravel Eloquent to find records with column matching an array
I'm struggling to find a way to check existing WHERE constraints on an Array-cast column.
My Thread model has a list of phone numbers...
class Thread extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'phone_numbers' => 'array'
    ];
}

So my table looks like
+---------------------------------+
| `phone_numbers` VARCHAR(256)    |
+---------------------------------+
| ["+15552345678","+15559876543"] |
| ["+15558675309"]                |
+---------------------------------+

To avoid duplicating a Thread with the same phone_numbers, I use firstOrCreate:
$phone_numbers = ["+15559876543","+15552345678"];
sort($phone_numbers); // always sort in case numbers are out of order
$thread = Thread::firstOrCreate(['phone_numbers' => $phone_numbers]);

As you might have guessed, this fails to detect the existing record because the phone_numbers column is just a string in the database, and sadly firstToCreate isn't clever enough to cast $phone_numbers according to the model rules, so it's not going to match.
I figured I might just manually convert $phone_numbers:
...
$thread = Thread::firstOrCreate(['phone_numbers' => json_encode($phone_numbers)]);

But this created an escaped string:
+---------------------------------------+
| `phone_numbers` VARCHAR(256)          |
+---------------------------------------+
| ["+15552345678","+15559876543"]       |
| ["+15558675309"]                      |
| "[\"+15552345678\",\"+15559876543\"]" | <-- new row
+---------------------------------------+

1) Is there a Laravel way of doing this comparison without manually converting my array to string, or
2) How can I convert it the way Eloquent does? I couldn't figure it out by source-diving.

Actually, it occurs to me that CHECKING for existence with json_encode is fine (Thread::where('phone_numbers', json_encode(["+15559876543","+15552345678"])->exists();) albeit ugly. The problem is when firstOrCreate() saves that value as "[\"+15552345678\",\"+15559876543\"]". So a workaround is not using firstOrCreate() but rather "manually" checking existence then creating or updating depending on that result. I just wish firstOrCreate was smarter about array|json-cast columns.

There is a way and it does not involve sorting json manually. MySQL has some json functions that could be of interest namely JSON_CONTAINS and JSON_OVERLAPS (the last one is only available on MySQL 8 onwards)
This is the definition for the firstOrCreate method. You can just leave $attributes empty and filter the results with a where instead.
public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes = [], array $values = [])
{
    if (! is_null($instance = (clone $this)->where($attributes)->first())) {
        return $instance;
    }

    return $this->createOrFirst($attributes, $values);
}

This approach kind of breaks is your phones are not unique though so be warned about that.
$phone_numbers = ["+15559876543","+15552345678"];

$thread = Thread::query()
    ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(phone_numbers, ?)', [json_encode($phone_numbers)])
    ->firstOrCreate(
        [],
        ['phone_numbers' => $phone_numbers],
    );

You don't really need to sort the $phone_numbers for JSON_CONTAINS() to work. You might want to do it anyways if you really want your phone_numbers column to be "sorted".
You could also use the query builder's built-in method for json_contains.
$phone_numbers = ["+15559876543","+15552345678"];

$thread = Thread::query()
    ->whereJsonContains('phone_numbers', $phone_numbers)
    ->firstOrCreate(
        [],
        ['phone_numbers' => $phone_numbers],
    );


Difference between JSON_CONTAINS and JSON_OVERLAPS:
Let's say you've got the following in your table
+------------------------+
| phones                 |
+------+-----------------+
| `id` | `phone_numbers` |
+------+-----------------+
|  1   | ["+111","+222"] |
|  2   | ["+333"]        |
|  3   | ["+444","+555"] |
+------+-----------------+


SELECT id FROM phones where JSON_CONTAINS(phone_numbers, '["+111"]')will return the row with id 1.
SELECT id FROM phones where JSON_CONTAINS(phone_numbers, '["+111","+333"]')will return nothing.
SELECT id FROM phones where JSON_CONTAINS(phone_numbers, '["+444","+555"]')will return the row with id 3.



SELECT id FROM phones where JSON_OVERLAPS(phone_numbers, '["+111"]') will return the row with id 1.
SELECT id FROM phones where JSON_OVERLAPS(phone_numbers, '["+111","+333"]')will return rows with id 1 and 2.
SELECT id FROM phones where JSON_OVERLAPS(phone_numbers, '["+444","+555"]')will return the row with id 3.


Ah, yeah PHPStorm autosuggested ->whereJsonContains() and wasn't sure if that could be used. The problem here, though, would be if two threads contain the same phone number it would grab that. The way your phone works (which is what we're replicating) you could have individual conversation threads with a single number, but also have group threads with subsets of those same numbers. My array column is actually replacing a column that's just a comma-separated list that required lots of implode/explodes and didn't take advantage of Eloquent's array cast.

The old code was sorting the numbers, imploding them, THEN comparing that string to the database. Until I find a better solution, I'm having to keep that ugly setup in place so we don't end up creating multiple threads for the same group.

Also just realized I've not updated mysql in a while, my env is still running 5.7. Trying json keywords directly in Sequel Pro kept throwing errors.

Another possibility is using a combination of JSON_LENGTH and JSON_CONTAINS to account for the duplicate scenarios. WHERE JSON_LENGTH(phones) = JSON_LENGTH('["+111","+222"]') AND JSON_CONTAINS(phones, '["+111","+222"]'). Still no need to sort
